# <fieldset> com flex-wrap não funciona corretamente no Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estou usando a propriedade CSS [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) em algumas `<div>` para que eu possa mostrá-las ou escondê-las sem que quebre a fluidez do layout. Porém eu notei que, quando meu container é um `<fieldset>`, o *wrap* não acontece no Google Chrome.

Vocês têm alguma ideia de como fazer renderizar corretamente no Chrome?

Ou alguma explicação para este comportamento?

Se quiserem testar [aqui tem um Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoazvX), abaixo tem um snippet, e logo após screenshots do comportamento na minha máquina (Windows 10, Chrome 69.0.3497.100 64 bits, Firefox 62.0 64bits).

[**EDIT** Existe [um repositório](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9) com os bugs de implementação nos navegadores.]

```css
/* vvv apenas para melhor apresentação vvv */
*, :before, :after { box-sizing: border-box;}
.content {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none; min-width: 0;
}
/* ^^^ apenas para melhor apresentação ^^^ */

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > .column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>&lt;div&gt;</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
</div>


<h3>&lt;fieldset&gt;</h3>
<fieldset class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">child</div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

#### Screenshot no Firefox

[image: Screenshot no Firefox]

---

#### Screenshot no Chrome

[image: Screenshot no Chrome]

Comment: Aparentemente é [um bug conhecido](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9), mas vou ficar no aguardo pelas respostas para que sirva como referência futura a alguém.

Comment: Carai, não consegui arrumar com flex de jeito nenhum... Só com float:left mesmo. Ai vc tira o flex do .row e coloca float: left; nas column que resolve. Outra opção é tentar como o Grid para ver como se comporta dentro do fieldset

Comment: Sim, que bizarro né?! Caí nesse problema porque as colunas do bootstrap 3 quebram quando tem um [`help-text`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-help-text) e elas ficam com alturas diferentes. Só que nesse form eu divido por setor com fieldset para poder dar um `disable` no set inteiro com menos overhead. Aí fiquei quebrando cabeça com isso e lembrei que a galera daqui pode dar uma mão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que um `<button>` ou `<fieldset>` não foi projetado para ser um container flex (ou grid).

Navegadores afetados:

- Chrome
- Edge
- Firefox (parcialmente corrigido na versão 52)
- Opera
- Safari (corrigido na versão 11)

Vale ressaltar que esse comportamento é aplicado a somente três elementos. São eles: `<button>`, `<fieldset>` e `<legend>`.

Acredito que a ideia por trás desse conceito está em prevenir que tornem um botão em uma tabela.

Para contarnar esse esse princípio você pode usar **uma simples técnica**:

> embrulhar/empacotar o conteúdo de um botão com um `span` e fazer o
>   `span` flex container.

```
<div>
    <button>
        <span><!-- using a div also works but is not valid HTML -->
            <span>Test</span>
            <span>Test</span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <p>
        <span>Test</span>
        <span>Test</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
button > span, p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Para um `fieldset` podemos usar outra técnica que é parecida com a primeira.

> Retirar a propriedade flex do `fieldset` e passar a mesma para uma `div` interna que também encapsulará a `div` item.

```css
.FlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}

.FlexItem {
  background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 8em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="FlexContainer">
    <div class="FlexItem">
      <input placeholder="esses campos">
    </div>
    <div class="FlexItem">
      <input placeholder="não deveriam estar">
    </div>
    <div class="FlexItem">
      <input placeholder="em vertical">
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

*NOTA: Embora eles não possam ser flex containers, um `button` pode ser um `flex` item.*

Resposta extraída dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements) do SO

Comment: Consegui achar os bugs [nesta página](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9). Eu entendo completamente o bug com os botões, mas um `fieldset` foi feito para ser um container, acho completamente bizarro não terem pensado nisso quando implementar flex no navegador. Não acha?

Comment: Ahhh.. e no Firefox o [único bug restante](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1397768) é com o `<button>` mesmo... Fieldset já tá liberado. :)

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Um `fieldset` é para ser um container mas não funciona com flex na maioria dos navegadores.

Comment: Pior é que só uso `fieldset` porque dando um `disabled` nele eu desativo todos os `inputs` filhos e isso é muito prático. Porque senão eu não usaria um elemento tão abandonado. hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio, achei um jeito de corrigir, dá uma olhada na resposta,

Comment: Eu descobri a solução do problema enquanto fazia a pergunta João. hahahaha
Postei a pergunta porque alguém ainda vai ter o mesmo problema e já fica documentado aqui. Vou dar um tempo pra galera postar mais coisas e depois aceito a resposta. Obrigado

Comment: @fernandosavio, quanto mais respostas mais valor agrega para a comunidade (respostas boas hahaha).

Comment: Sim.. tô na esperança que alguém venha com uma solução muito louca. Tô só pela criatividade da galera. hahahaha

Comment: Cade as outras repostas hahaha, queria ver outras soluções